# How to check two indices of a string to see if the characters match

Tags: java, string, charat

I am trying to check two different indices to see if they match. In my case I am checking indices 3 and 4. I have no problem determining if they match or not, but if my string is too short and does not have a character in at index 3 or 4 my program throws a fit.

Here is a copy of my code. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Checks the characters in a String at indices 3 and 4 to see if those characters match
 * @param input String to check
 * @return "MATCH" if String's indices 3 and 4 have the same letter, "NO MATCH" if String's
 * indices 3 and 4 do not have the same letter, "N/A" if the String is too short to have a letter at index 3 or index 4
 */
private static String method4(String input) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your word? ");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    int len = input.length();

    if (len < 4) {
        System.out.println("N/A");
    }
    else{
        char char1 = input.charAt(3);
        char char2 = input.charAt(4);
        if ((char1) == (char2)) {
        System.out.println("MATCH");
    }}
    else
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to add the [tag:java] tag to your question. Also, instead of saying _"my program throws a fit"_, try to look for the error message, check what it says, and then include it in your post for others to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The method your using `charAt` is zero based like an array.

```
if (len < 4) {
    System.out.println("N/A");
}
```

Only ensures that the string has at least 4 characters, the fourth having index 3.

```
"abcd".charAt(3) == 'd'
```

So when the the string has exactly 4 characters `input.charAt(4)` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("What is your word? ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    int len = str.length();

    if (len < 5)
        System.out.println("N/A");
    else if (str.charAt(3) == str.charAt(4))
        System.out.println("MATCH");
    else
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

As mentiont in other post:

```
String str = "abcd";
str.legnth == 4
str.charAt(3) == 'd' // zero-based
```